# How do you call an assumption that makes the problem at hand simpler vs one that complicates it?

Tags: expressions

In Hebrew, we have a way of classifying assumptions as either (roughly translated) "relieving" or "worsening" based on whether they "err on the side of caution" for the latter or otherwise for the former, e.g. when trying to secure an airport, a "relieving" assumption would be to assume that no dangerous materials can enter the duty free area, therefore there is no need to have a security checkpoint between that area and the gate, while a "worsening" assumption would be to have that checkpoint.

Is this phrasing valid in English? If not, is there another similar phrasing?

Comment: How can the assumption that “no dangerous material can enter the duty free area” be “relieving ”? It rather appears to be “dangerously inaccurate” instead.

Comment: The assumption is made after many measures were taken to ensure that dangerous materials cannot enter that area (a security checkpoint before the area, security checks on entered goods etc.). After all these measures were taken, one can assume (this is still an assumption, albeit with a stronger basis) that no dangerous materials enter there. One could instead assume that there are still some ways dangerous materials could enter that area, and have another checkpoint at the gate.

Comment: Ok, so what’s the difference with the “worsening” assumption if all precautionary measures have already been taken?

Comment: I don't know about "assumptions", but in general one can adopt a *strict* vs. *relaxed*  policy - which I believe translates as מחמיר או מקל.

Comment: @user240918 it's hard to design a set of precautionary measures that give you an absolute guarantee that no dangerous materials can enter that area - for example, a passenger could form a knife from the materials found in the duty free shops and get it on board.

Comment: @michael.hor257k That sounds right! thanks :) (you can post this as the answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the given context, one would be more likely to speak about ***policies***, rather than ***assumptions***.

Assuming that the original classifications you are trying to translate to English are מחמיר and מקל, I would suggest using **strict** and ***relaxed*** to characterize the types of policy one can adopt.

---

*A side note: this is a good example of how a word can have a single meaning in one language, but two (or more) meanings in another.*

Answer (score 0):

The OP has already noted the right word, *worse*. Going forward, the apt phrase would be *worst-case scenario*.

> Securing an airport for the worst case scenario.

Or,

> Securing an airport assuming the worst case.

*See:*
[Worst-case scenario](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Worst-case_scenario) (WP)

> A worst-case scenario is a concept in risk management wherein the planner, in planning for potential disasters, considers the most severe possible outcome that can reasonably be projected to occur in a given situation. Conceiving of worst-case scenarios is a common form of strategic planning, specifically scenario planning, to prepare for and minimize contingencies that could result in accidents, quality problems, or other issues.